# aws Amplify angular setting using sso

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am trying to build an angular application using amplify sign on as described in this link https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/angular/connected-components/authenticator/advanced

everything works fine, I was able to sign in and sign out from my amplify application but I want to use this amplify application as SSO application so other applications can be redirected to amplify SSO app and sign in and redirected back after sing in
is there any other setting I need to do with that application or is there an example how to use amplify application as SSO
I don't want to use hosting UI in AWS I want to create custom page for login.

I appreciate your help

Comment: The functionality you are describing is of an Identity Server. Amplify is not a Identity Server, while Cognito is. You can Use Cognito Hosted UI for that functionality. To customize UI, Cognito supports attaching a new CSS file. Refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-ui-customization.html